# Active Admin: How to customize the main menu (at the top of the page)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, menu, activeadmin

This is probably simple, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

In ActiveAdmin, I'd like to customize the behavior of the menu at the top of the page, particularly this link for the currently logged in user:

[image]

In all my searching, I haven't been able to find a way of altering the links in the top-right corner.

I'd like to change the text, where the link points to, and possible add links to this area of the menu.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can modify **config/initializers/active_admin.rb**.

For **ActiveAdmin 0.6.0**, add these lines :

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  # Customize Up Right menu
  config.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|
      menu.add  :label  => 'click me', # text of your link
        :url            => proc{ my_awesome_path }, # route of your link
        :html_options   => {:style => 'float:left;'}, # attributes added in the DOM of your link
        :if             => proc{ 1 < 2 } # condition to display the link

      menu.add  :label  => proc{ display_name current_active_admin_user }, # email of the current admin user logged
        :url            => proc { my_other_awesome_path },
        :html_options   => {:style => 'float:left;'},
        :id             => 'current_user',
        :if             => proc{ current_active_admin_user? }

      admin.add_logout_button_to_menu menu, 100, :style => 'float:left;' # logout link
    end
  end
end
```

For **ActiveAdmin 0.4.2** and before, you have to add this code at the end of the same file :

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  # ...
end

module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class HeaderRenderer
      alias_method :default_to_html, :to_html
      def to_html
        default_to_html.sub(current_admin_user.email, "<a style='text-decoration: underline;' href='#{my_awesome_path}'>#{current_admin_user.email}</b>").html_safe
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Works for me with 'admin' as the namespace. Thanks!

Comment: Finally found the official docs for this: http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/1-general-configuration.html#utility_navigation

Answer (score 2):

Just type the following in initializers file:

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
 config.namespace :admin do |admin|
   admin.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|
     menu.add label: "ActiveAdmin.info", url: "http://www.activeadmin.info",
                                      html_options: { target: :blank }
     admin.add_current_user_to_menu  menu
     admin.add_logout_button_to_menu menu
   end
 end
end
```