# Change the colour of the header/navbar dynamically based on ENV ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'd like to change the colour from grey to blue/purple/green/grey based on an ENV variable which stores our environment. Just as a quick visual queue for our devs.

For example this [image] to this [image] which would be affecting this CSS [image]

I don't think I need JavaScript, and am hoping to just have an if with the css in code but I'm unsure how. I think I should be able to able to change something in one of the following files to make it work but I can't piece together how:

```
config/initializers/active_admin.rb
app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.scss
```

Rails and Gem Versions

```
Rails 6.0.5.1
activeadmin (2.2.0, 2.0.0)
activerecord (6.0.5.1, 6.0.4.7, 5.2.6.3, 5.2.4.6)
```

Possibly Related

- [Active Admin: How to customize the main menu (at the top of the page)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904811/active-admin-how-to-customize-the-main-menu-at-the-top-of-the-page)
- [How can I modify the "header" section in ActiveAdmin, in each request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542630/how-can-i-modify-the-header-section-in-activeadmin-in-each-request)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `register_stylesheet` option in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` to load css stylesheet that overrides default styles, like:

```
  config.register_stylesheet 'custom_active_admin.scss', if: ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] == 'staging'
```

And inside `custom_active_admin.scss` you can override #header or .header CSS elements as you need.

---

If you need, you can make css file selection more complex by using 'if' or 'case' statements in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`:

```
  if ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] == 'staging'
    css_file_name = 'active_admin_staging.css'
  else
    css_file_name = 'active_admin_development.css'
  end

  config.register_stylesheet css_file_name
```

Comment: Looks my problem is complicated by using .scss files. Doing what you suggested with the followinf css didn't work 
```#header {
    background-color: #7741e0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #7741e0, #34265e);
}```

Comment: There are 2 things that can go wrong:
- custom scss file is not loaded -> you can check it in browser inspector Network tab
- file is loaded but CSS styles are not correct. You can try to override styles in browser inspector and then copy it to file.
Can you check which part exactly is not working? cheers